# How to replace cells if they contain part of a string in R

Tags: r, replace, contains, recode

I have columns with different ratings from 1-5 with descriptors next to the number. The format is "number dash descriptor", ex. "1 - very happy" or "5 - hungry". I want to replace these with just the number, but there are a lot of different descriptors and too many to recode all manually.

Because they all include a dash, I'm sure there must be a way to do something like replace all instances of cells that contain "1 -" with "1", but I can't seem to make anything simple work.

Any help is appreciated!

I can use str_contains to find cells that contain a dash, but can't make that work with replace in dplyr.

Answer (score 2):

Since we know that `' -'` is assured in all cells, why not just split the string by `' -'` and take the first element instead of doing the regex method which can potential match "a lot of different descriptors" mentioned.

```
> df<-data.frame(number_dash_descriptor=c('1 - very happy','4 - fafdf132321)(*&^%$#','5 - hungry'))
> df
   number_dash_descriptor
1          1 - very happy
2 4 - fafdf132321)(*&^%$#
3              5 - hungry
> df%>%mutate(number_dash_descriptor= str_split(number_dash_descriptor, ' -')%>%sapply("[[",1))
  number_dash_descriptor
1                      1
2                      4
3                      5
```

Comment: Hi Joy, welcome to Stack Overflow. Slight correction: the regex method cannot "potentially match a lot of different descriptors" if it's properly formulated.

Comment: @Mark How about a string like "1 - 1 - 2 - 3 -"?

Comment: Joy you might want to read the documentation for `str_extract`- it takes the first match from a string, so something like `str_extract("1 - 1 - 2 - 3 -", "\\d+")` matches the first 1

Comment: @Mark Ok, I see. It works for positive values then. However, it still won't be applicable for some situations, e.g., negative scores are totally possible in ratings. `str_extract("-1 - not quite good", "\\d ")` misses the negative operator, while the method I suggest still works. I am just here to give a robust solution.

Comment: Nice pick up! In that case, it'd have to be `'[\\d-]+'` 

Comment: str_extract("-1 - not quite good", "\\d ") doesn't give the right answer even in the case without the minus sign, as it gets the space afterwards as well. I'd recommend reading about regexes

Comment: How would I do this for all columns in the df at once?

Comment: @SophiaL You can use apply() on the df columns.  `df%<>% apply(2，FUN= function(x) {str_split(x, 
 ' -') %>% sapply('[[', 1)})`.

Answer (score 1):

To extract numbers from text strings in R, I would use the `{stringr}` package.

First, lets reproduce your data in a simple dataframe:

```
library(dplyr)

data <- tibble("values" = c("1 - very happy", "5 - hungry", "3 - average"))
```

We can use `str_extract` from the `{stringr}` package to extract the first single character from a string, using the regex syntax for any character (`.`) at the beginning of the string (`^`):

```
install.packages("stringr")
library(stringr)
data |> 
  mutate(numbers = stringr::str_extract(values, "^.") |> as.numeric())
```

But this won't work if there are numbers with more than a single digit. So, we can use regex for any number of any length (`\\d+`) in `str_extract` to extract only numbers from a string, no matter in which part of the string they are in:

```
data |> 
  mutate(numbers = stringr::str_extract(values, "\\d+") |> as.numeric())
```

This method allows us to also find any number that is before a dash symbol:

```
data |> 
  mutate(numbers = stringr::str_extract(values, "\\d+ -"),
         numbers = stringr::str_remove(numbers, " -") |> as.numeric())
```

Note that we have to remove the dash afterwards. This can be avoided using what is called I regex a positive lookahead, that is, find things that match the criteria but also come before other things, like extracting any number that comes before a space and dash symbols:

```
data |> 
  mutate(numbers = stringr::str_extract(values, "\\d+(?= -)") |> as.numeric())
```

Finally, other packages such as `{readr}` have functions that help with these kind of data cleaning tasks:

```
data |> 
  mutate(numbers = readr::parse_number(values))
```

Answer (score 1):

An approach with `sub`, making sure only numbers are considered by using a capture group on the digit(s) (`\\d+`) at the beginning of the string (`^`).

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(desc_new = as.numeric(sub("(^\\d+) - .*", "\\1", desc)))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  desc           desc_new
  <chr>             <dbl>
1 1 - very happy        1
2 5 - hungry            5
```

##### Data

```
df <- structure(list(desc = c("1 - very happy", "5 - hungry")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```